# How to change front end of kie workbench of jbpm 6.5?

Tags: java, jsp, jbpm, kie-wb

[This is Login page of kie wb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Fzk.png)
[Home page of kie-wb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsVYy.png) 
1. How to remove "KIE IDE" Logo from Login Page and insert other Logo Or add any other String?
2. Is there possible any way to change only Menu items name (e.g Authoring to Developer Job) ?

I want to customise Kie-wb.jsp ? But went into location jbpm-installer/lib, there i found kie-server-6.5.0.Final-wildfly-10.0.0.Final.war file, but i couldnt find kie-wb.jsp page in that war ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at the wrong place since [KIE Server](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/pt06.html) is just an execution server with remote APIs and does not provide any GUI. What you want to edit is KIE Workbench (or jBPM Console) WAR file where you will find `login.jsp`. You can edit this file to change the logo or make some changes in `styles/login-screen.css` to customize background etc.

When it comes to your second question, most of the strings in KIE Workbench (including menu items) are localized so it should not be hard to find *Authoring* or other names you want to replace. But I am not sure where exactly they are located.

Comment: Thanks. In jbpm-console.war file , I was able to edit Login.jsp , Logout.jsp.  I search whole jbpm-console war to change names like Authoring but was unable to location.

Comment: You can find those menu items in [Constants.properties](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng/blob/6.5.x/jbpm-console-ng-bpm-home/jbpm-console-ng-bpm-home-client/src/main/resources/org/jbpm/console/ng/bh/client/i18n/Constants.properties) but I am afraid they end up compiled by GWT in one of the `*.cache.js` files in `org.kie.workbench.KIEWebapp` and it is hard to find the right _Authoring_ string there. If you want to change it, you will probably need to edit **Constants.properties** file and compile jBPM Console on your own.

Comment: actually, menu items cannot be changed in constants.properties. Bdw thanks for helping.